# Azure Maps reverse geocoding problem with coordinates

Tags: azure, reverse-geocoding, azure-maps

I started using Azure Maps **reverse geocoding** REST API endpoint and for requests with coordinates from my region (Poland) its returning results from Saudi Arabia

**My request:**

**Lat - 51.762036
Long - 19.532306**

**curl**

```
curl --location 'https://atlas.microsoft.com/reverseGeocode?subscription-key={mySubscriptionKey}&
api-version=2023-06-01&
coordinates=51.762036%2C%2019.532306'
```

**http**

```
GET /reverseGeocode?
subscription-key={mySubscriptionKey}&
api-version=2023-06-01&
coordinates=51.762036, 19.532306 HTTP/1.1
Host: atlas.microsoft.com
```

And this is my **results**:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    51.76203536987305,
                    19.532306671142578
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "geocodePoints": [
                    {
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [
                                51.76203536987305,
                                19.532306671142578
                            ]
                        },
                        "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
                        "usageTypes": [
                            "Display"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "address": {
                    "adminDistricts": [
                        {
                            "shortName": "Eastern"
                        }
                    ],
                    "countryRegion": {
                        "name": "Saudi Arabia",
                        "iso": "SA"
                    },
                    "formattedAddress": "Eastern"
                },
                "confidence": "Medium",
                "matchCodes": [
                    "Good",
                    "UpHierarchy"
                ],
                "type": "AdminDivision1"
            },
            "bbox": [
                51.7210569322467,
                19.50333628815002,
                51.8030138074994,
                19.561277054135136
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For some coordinates presented on samples it works fine, is there something I'm doing wrong with my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Maps aligns with the geospatial standard of "longitude, latitude" (similar to x,y), reverse the numbers in your coordinates and you should see results in the right part of the world.

Note, the response is in GeoJSON format which is an open geospatial standard format. Its specification requires the "longitude, latitude" format.